# Unusual behavior from Firebase Authentication when signing in using existing account email

Tags: oauth, firebase, firebase-authentication

Not sure what is happening or Why, but If i create a new user using Firebase facebook Oauth with say email 123@gmail.com and then sign in using Firebase google Oauth with the same email (123@gmail.com) , Firebase does not give me an error that an account already exists with this email. it just updates the provider under users tab. However, if i first create a user with Google Oauth using email (123@gmail.com) and then try sign using Facebook Oauth with the same email there is an error stating that account already exists.

Comment: That is the current intended behavior because google accounts are verified as google issues that gmail account whereas a facebook account using a google issued email is not.

Comment: didnt know that. thanks