# Why firebase does overwrite previous authentication provider when we sign-up using Google OAuth?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

## Problem

Firebase force overwrites previous authentication provider when we sign-up using Google OAuth.

## Precondition

- Both GitHub account and Google one are the same email.
- **Disallow** multiple accounts with the same email address

## Expected Behavior

1. Sign-up using GitHub OAuth
2. A new account (ACCOUNT_1) is created on Firebase Auth
3. Sign-out
4. Sign-up using Google OAuth, "auth/account-exists-with-different-credential" error occurs.

## Actual

1. Sign-up using GitHub OAuth
2. A new account (ACCOUNT_1) is created on Firebase Auth
3. Sign-out
4. Sign-up using Google OAuth
5. **ACCOUNT_1 is overwritten by Google OAuth provider on Firebase.**
6. Sign-in using GitHub OAuth, "auth/account-exists-with-different-credential" error occurs.

## What I tried

- When a new account is created first time, I force updated **emailVerified = True** using Cloud Functions.

I saw the bellow article:

- [oauth - Unusual behavior from Firebase Authentication when signing in using existing account email - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39432633/unusual-behavior-from-firebase-authentication-when-signing-in-using-existing-acc)

In my understanding, Google OAuth process only overwrites an account with non-verified email.

Comment: As bojeil said in the comment you linked: Google is the preferred provider for GMail addresses. Also see https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/firebase-talk/liu/firebase-talk/ms_NVQem_Cw/8g7BFk1IAAAJ (linked from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37947944/authentication-using-facebook-at-first-and-then-google-causes-an-error-in-fireba/37973121#37973121)

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen thank you for your response. I understood, Unfortunately, It is not a bug. But I can not agree with Google's concept...

Comment: That is not a question anyone here on Stack Overflow can answer. If you'd like this behavior to be changed, I recommend that you [file a bug report or feature request](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features/).

Comment: Yes, I'll send the feature request.